# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' - Py3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting following error with Python3 but the function works fine with Python2

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import os

def lock_me(filename, dirname, permissions):
        owns_lock = 0
        try:
            with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=str(os.getpid())) as temp_file:
                
                temp_file.write("loki")
                temp_file.flush()

                os.chmod(temp_file.name, permissions)
     

                print("Lock: acquired %s", filename)
                owns_lock += 1

            return True
        except OSError as e:
            raise
            
lock_me("loki", "agrawal", 0o644)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    lock_me("loki", "agrawal", 0o644)
  File "main.py", line 8, in lock_me
    temp_file.write("loki")
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 483, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

What is the safest change to make here, so that it does not break any existing things?

Comment: What's the _full_ error message?

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  In particular, include the entire error message, plus useful `print` tracing to show the offending values and their origins.  What are the type and value of the offending variable, and where did you have it as a byte object?

Comment: Updated the question, with the MRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode the string, this will convert the `string` object into a `byte` object :

```
temp_file.write("loki".encode('utf-8')))
```

Or you can simply do :

```
temp_file.write("loki".encode()))
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference?

encode vs encode('utf-8')?

Comment: There is no difference, default value for the `encode()` function is `'utf-8'`. Its just less code, and looks cleaner

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: @RoshinRaphel - The default for `encode` is what `sys.getdefaultencoding()` says. This can bite you when you have a codepage based Windows machine or if its utf-16.

Comment: yes but I am not sure where it will bite me. And I am confused after reading @tdelaney answer

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal Just use encode('utf-8')

Answer (score 4):

[`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) defaults to write-binary mode. You can change the mode and add an encoding instead

```
with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=str(os.getpid()), mode="w",
        encoding="utf-8") as temp_file:`
```

If you leave out encoding, you'll get the default encoding for your environment as shown in `sys.getdefaultencoding()`. Its generally better to be specific about encoding so that other programs know how to read it - even in a different environment with a different encoding. To keep life complicated, UTF-8 is the encoding of choice for everyone but Microsoft, which tends to default to UTF-16-LE or the local code page, depending on the tool.

Comment: This does not work in 2.7

TypeError: NamedTemporaryFile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Comment: You asked for a python 3 solution that doesn't break anything. If you want 2 to 3 compatibility, that's a different story. Since 2 has been end-of-lifed, the answer there is to fork, keep 2 code bases and retire 2 as soon as possible. Its been a decade.